# PHP and XML: getElementByType

Tags: php, html, xml

I'm somewhat new to php and I'm trying to loop through my XML file in order to extract data and display it in HTML. I know how to do the display to HTML part, but I'm a little confused for what to do for the XML part.

Here is a sample file of what I am trying to do (you can picture it as a categorized list of movies where groupType would be genre):

```
<mainGroup>

    <groupHeading type="heading">This is a sample heading</groupHeading>
    <group type="groupType1">
      <title>Title1</title>
      <date when="0001"></date>
    </group>

    <group type="groupType1">
      <title>Title2</title>
      <date when="0002"></date>
    </group>

    <group type="groupType2">
      <title>Title3</title>
      <date when="0003"></date>
    </group>

</mainGroup>
... There are more mainGroups with differet group types etc
```

Basically, I will have 10+ mainGroups, with many different groups inside of it, so I need a way to loop through these using php. The main problem is the fact that I need someway to "getElementBy Type()", but that does not exist.

If anything is confusing, I can elaborate more, I'm still a novice to php so I hope I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

real simple --> use PHP's `simplexml`  ---> live demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/i4MRGI

```
$xmlstr = '<mainGroup>
<groupHeading type="heading">This is a sample heading</groupHeading>
    <group type="groupType1">
        <title>Title1</title>
        <date when="0001"></date>
    </group>
    <group type="groupType1">
        <title>Title2</title>
        <date when="0002"></date>
    </group>
    <group type="groupType2">
        <title>Title3</title>
        <date when="0003"></date>
    </group>
</mainGroup>';

// create simplexml object
$xml=simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);

// loop through all <groupheading>, we use an xpath-query...
foreach ($xml->xpath("//groupHeading") as $gh) {

    echo($gh),'<br />';

} 

// now the titles under every group with groupType1...

foreach ($xml->xpath("//group[@type='groupType1']/title") as $gt1) {

echo $gt1,'<br />';
}
```

EDIT: echo title of each groupHeading, then titles of child-nodes  if grouptype=1:
---> see new demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/eMuyr5

```
foreach ($xml->groupHeading as $gh) {

    echo($gh),'<br />';

    foreach ($gh->xpath("//group[@type='groupType1']/title") as $gt1) {

      echo $gt1,'<br />';

   }
}
```

Comment: I need to keep track of the group heading as it is going to be the head of a section, so just finding it before getting all of the groups won't work. There are multiple mainGroups, so I would need to specify those.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the edit. Simple XML seems like it is the way to go as it is much easier to separate elements out. Thanks

Comment: @sl133 now see my edit, end of answer. it should do exactly what you wanted, does it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [PHP DOM](http://php.net/dom)

If you wanted to search groups for a particular type and then get the results you could do something like this:

EDIT - `$string` would be your XML. If you needed to load it from a file you can do 
`$string = file_get_contents('/path/to/your/file');`

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($string);

$searchtype = "groupType1";
$results = array();

$groups = $dom->getElementsByTagName('group');
foreach( $groups as $g ) { 
    if( $g->getAttribute('type') == $searchtype ) { 
        $results[] = array(
            'title' =>$g->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date'  =>$g->getElementsByTagName('date')->item(0)->getAttribute('when')
            );  
    }   
}

print_r($results);
```

Comment: Do you think it would be easier to use classes to organize if I had about 200+ different groups, or would it be easier to loop?

Comment: Unfortunately PHP DOM omits getElementsByClassName() so it wouldn't really help. My example would search all groups regardless of maingroup. If that's what you're trying to do it's likely faster to search them all than doing a nested loop to find the particular main group ... if you want to find a main group first just change the tag from group to maingroup and compare types or whatever other attribute you need.